# Compare two tables with different column numbers in sql

Tags: sql, union, sybase

I am using Sybase for my SQL coding.

I was comparing tables which have the same columns such as follows:

```
SELECT name, date, time, location
FROM
(SELECT * FROM table1
UNION ALL  
SELECT * FROM table2) data
GROUP BY name, date, time, location
HAVING count(*)!=2
```

Now, I want to be able to compare the table1 and table2 but now table2 has another column called `origin` and I am not sure on how to extend my current logic to make it happen.

```
---Intention: to be able to compare the two tables with varying column numbers
---How to modify this code to do it?

I want to be able to show the differences between the two tables after the query.
```

May someone guide me? I dont want to use joins or minus, I prefer to use the UNION way.

Comment: It is uncommon for two tables to have the exact same structure. So, your first case is a very special case. Usually, tables are different and you must name the columns you want to use: `SELECT name, date, time, location FROM table1 UNION ALL ...`.

Comment: Why do you want to group by origin when one of the tables doesn't have that column? That doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner This is my sample code, I know it is incorrect and I updated the code. But how can I show the differences between the two tables?

Comment: If one table has a column more than the other, then *all* rows are consequently different, correct?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner That is correct, and how do  I achieve that?

Comment: Select all rows from both tables? Either with two separate queries or with a union query containing pseudo columns: `SELECT name, date, time, location, origin FROM table2 UNION ALL SELECT name, date, time, location, null as origin FROM table1`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner may you post it as a solution as it works good, thank you. so i can accept it

Answer (score 1):

If you want to union two different tables, you must make up missing columns. E.g.:

```
SELECT name, date, time, location, origin FROM table2
UNION ALL
SELECT name, date, time, location, null as origin FROM table1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you actually want to *ignore* the extra column. The  problem with using `select *` is that things can change.

```
SELECT name, date, time, location
FROM (
    SELECT name, date, time, location FROM table1
    UNION ALL  
    SELECT name, date, time, location FROM table2
) data
GROUP BY name, date, time, location
HAVING count(*) != 2
```

If you're not going to use `select *` in one half of the union there isn't any reason include `origin` in the first place.